# How to include angular-uib star rating in ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I've been trying to include uib star rating in ui grid using the celltemplate field but it returns an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".
After a little debugging i found out that it is not able to understand the uib-rating directive given in celltemplate .(i've included tpls.js)

```
 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name:'FirstName', width:100, enableCellEdit: true },
    { name:'Rating', width:75, 
        cellTemplate:'<div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl"><h4>Default</h4><uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating></div>' 
    },
    { name:'Age', width:50 , enableCellEdit: true },
    { name:'Gender', width:75 , enableCellEdit: true },
    { name:'Salary', width:75, enableCellEdit: true }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template could be simply as in the code below:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
    <uib-rating ng-model="row.entity.Rating" max="10" readonly="isReadonly">
    </uib-rating>
</div>
```

In ui-grid template you can refer the field value as `row.entity.[fieldname]`. Check in: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Templating

Check this working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/59ToE2XWD9pXlD6tjpDs